# Linq .Count() from another table with inner join (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

So I have been trying to do this for a couple of hours by now but I still can't get it

Tables are like this.

```
**Questions** 
   -  IDQuestion, IDSubject, DNI, others..
**Answers**
   - IDQuestion , IDAnswer, DNICreator, others..
**StudentsPersonalinformation (just to get names, nothing related to the answers)**
   - name, surname, DNI, others..
```

What i want to do is within the linq query get the amount of answers of a question. What I already have is this

```
var querySubjectQuestions = (from questions in db.questions
join studentspersonalinformation in db.studentspersonalinformation on questions.DNI equals studentspersonalinformation.DNI
where questions.IDSubject == IDSubject && questions.status == 1
select new
{
    IDQuestion = questions.IDQuestion,
    Title = questions.title,
    Date = questions.date,
    studentName = studentspersonalinformation.name,
    studentSurname = studentspersonalinformation.surname,
}).OrderByDescending(c => c.Date);
```

But still don't know where to put the .Count from the other table where the IDQuestion equals the one it is querying.

Thanks :)

Comment: How is `studentspersonalinformation` related to your problem? I though it was about questions and answers?

Comment: This would be easier to do in SQL.

Comment: Can you provide your C# entities? i.e. `Question`, `Answer`, and `StudentPersoanlInformation`?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ELNc66f.png C# Entities. What I want to get is the Count of answers within a question

Comment: So no foreign keys on these tables?

Comment: I made them in MySQL so yeah, I had some trouble with that also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var querySubjectQuestions = (from questions in db.questions
                             join studentspersonalinformation in db.studentspersonalinformation on questions.DNI equals studentspersonalinformation.DNI
                             where questions.IDSubject == IDSubject && questions.status == 1
                             select new
                             {
                                 IDQuestion = questions.IDQuestion,
                                 Title = questions.title,
                                 Date = questions.date,
                                 studentName = studentspersonalinformation.name,
                                 studentSurname = studentspersonalinformation.surname,
                                 noAnswers = (from answer in db.answers 
                                             where answer.IDQuestion == questions.IDQuestion)
                                             select answer).Count()
                              }).OrderByDescending(c => c.Date);
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT!!! It worked with a little bit of tweaks (from answers in db.answers 
                                                              where answers.IDQuestion == questions.IDQuestion
                                                              select answers).Count()

Answer (score 0):

Without your c# entities of your DB tables, this is the best I can do.

```
select new
{
    IDQuestion = questions.IDQuestion,
    Title = questions.title,
    Date = questions.date,
    studentName = studentspersonalinformation.name,
    studentSurname = studentspersonalinformation.surname,
    noAnswer = questions.Answers.Count()
}
```